# Make div fill rest of parent and grow with content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a box with a `min-height` that is supposed to show some active text which changes on button click (button won't work in snippet, please emulate click by changing opacity in respective class).

The Button is supposed to always be located at the bottom of the box and `.content` shall fill the rest of the box with its text starting at the beginning. **Additionally, since the text length varies, I want the box to grow with the text (button still at the bottom and `.content` above).**

How can I do so? That's how far I got:

```css
.item-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item-3 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 20rem;
  width: 400px;
  
  padding: 4rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

button {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content">
    <p class="item item-1">Test 1<p/>
    <p class="item item-2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed  diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. d tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <p/>
    <p class="item item-3">Test 3<p/>
  </div>
  
  <button id="next">Next</button>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");

var addContent = function() {
  content.innerHTML += " The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
}
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #f3aaf3;
  min-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn {
  bottom: 16px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="content" class="content">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
  </div>
  <button class="btn" onclick="addContent()">Add content</button>
</div>
```

Updated the snippet:

[image]

Updated again, now it will grow with the content with the button staying at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot! But is there a way to make the text never reach the button? The box is supposed to grow with all its content. Since I need css transitions for changing text, I have all elements ready with only one being visible. Is there a way to consider this as well?

Comment: And as you can see in my edited snippet - I achieved to make the text wrapper fill the rest of the container with flex. But the box is not growing with its content.

Comment: Updated the snippet. It is possible to set the content max-height (or height). If the text overflows the height - the scrollbar will be shown. If you want to achieve something different, you would need to provide more explanation details.

Comment: Fixed positions - use absolute/fixed position for child and relative for a parent. Adjustable position (grow) - use flex with `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Do you know how to handle let's say 3 different text elements of different length with an opacity transition? So that at first text 1 is active and visible and on button click text 2 will be revealed using that opacity transition. I know how to do it using position absolute on the text elements to have them lie on one another, then change the opacity on click - using absolute though will make the automated box-height thing stop working.

Comment: nvm thats a new question, I'll open a new topic!